# android voally exception error not showing on the log cat

Tags: android, android-volley

I have the below code using volley, I am having a blank page when opening the app , but when I click on my php link its returning values.

why its showing white blank on the opening ? I am getting an exception but am not able to read it can you help me with that ?

this is a line of the error

```
D/Volley(4754): [1] 2.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
```

this is the code

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("r", response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    System.out.print(response);

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("path"));
                            movie.setRating(obj.getString("description"));
                          //  movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("description"))
                                //    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getString("likes"));
                          //  movie.setYear(obj.getInt("likes"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("comments");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.print(error);
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });
```

this is the log cat

```
07-30 13:06:47.319: I/PersonaManager(4754): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
07-30 13:06:47.409: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4754): Parent view is not a TextView
07-30 13:06:47.449: D/AbsListView(4754): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-30 13:06:47.549: D/AbsListView(4754): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
07-30 13:06:47.549: D/AbsListView(4754): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-30 13:06:47.579: D/AbsListView(4754): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
07-30 13:06:47.579: D/AbsListView(4754): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-30 13:06:47.664: I/(4754): PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
07-30 13:06:47.754: D/mali_winsys(4754): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
07-30 13:06:47.769: D/OpenGLRenderer(4754): Enabling debug mode 0
07-30 13:06:47.779: D/ProgressBar(4754): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-30 13:06:47.779: D/ProgressBar(4754): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-30 13:06:47.779: D/ProgressBar(4754): updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
07-30 13:06:47.779: D/ProgressBar(4754): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
07-30 13:06:47.779: D/AbsListView(4754): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-30 13:06:47.809: D/mali_winsys(4754): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
07-30 13:06:47.834: D/AbsListView(4754): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-30 13:06:47.904: D/AbsListView(4754): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-30 13:06:47.979: I/System.out(4754): Thread-6768(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
07-30 13:06:47.979: I/System.out(4754): Thread-6768(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
07-30 13:06:48.049: D/Volley(4754): [1] 2.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
07-30 13:06:48.064: D/AbsListView(4754): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-30 13:06:48.069: E/ViewRootImpl(4754): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Edit:

after  I removed the word "result", I was to able to catch the error :

> ```
> 07-30 13:32:41.384: W/System.err(16258): org.json.JSONException: Value
> ```
>
> [{"path":"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg","comments":"
>   Very nice","description":"long story","likes":"5","name":"50 shade of
>   gray"},{"path":"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2jpg","comments":"
>   beautiful","description":"Robots","likes":"7","name":"Transformers"},{"path":"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/3.jpg","comments":"
>   wow","description":"hulk and iron
>   man","likes":"8","name":"Avangeers"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray
>   cannot be converted to JSONObject

but In my php I have edit this

`echo json_encode(array($result));` should'nt encode it ?

Comment: I think to find the answer you have to dig into the JsonArrayRequest class or you have to provide this class info with url. So i can look into it.

Comment: @EEJ Ill be glad if you can help me , ill provide what you need. but jssonarrayresuest its something realted to volley jar . I just import it . check my edit for the url . I guess my mistake with the word result , should it be there ?

Comment: provide me JsonArrayRequest source code and url which you using to fetch the data

Comment: @EEJ check my edit question please, and this is the url :http://justedhak.comlu.com/movies.php ... JsonArrayRequest   is realted to the library I can't access to it

Comment: @EEJ ok I am able to have an error on log cat can you check it please

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two problem in your resposne which are given below with the solutions:-

1.Your resposne is not an appropriate **json object**. You response contains **?>** at the end which raised up the parsing error. So just removed it from the api response.

2.Your resposne is actually a **json object**. So instead of using  **JsonArrayRequest** use **JsonObjectRequest** class.

Have Peace and Enjoy!!!

Comment: isnt there another way of using jsonobejct request ? cant I keep using jsonarrayrequest?

Comment: return your response like array means enclose your response inside square bracket then you can use JsonArrayRequest.

Comment: but the response is enclose with brackets . check my php file

Comment: http://justedhak.comlu.com/movies.php I have noticed 2 brackets at the start , is it normal   ? @eej

Comment: Your resposnse contains two square brackets at begin & end however it suppose to  be only one open and close brace otherwise it will consider it nested array.

Comment: how to remove one bracket ? where possible the probllem could be ? @eej

Comment: You can look at your php code. I think you are adding array inside array before encoding it as an json array or somethig else...